# VS2008 - Memory issue when generating manifest

Tags: visual-studio-2008, manifest

Having made changes and going into debug mode in Visual studio 2008, I often get messages such as:

> "Problem generating manifest. Insufficient memory to continue the
>   execution of the program.
>   \WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets   2341 
>   9  ZEUS(my project name)"

By closing and reopening VS the problem temorarily goes away - as though some temp core is being freed up. My PC has lots of memory available - but VS seems limited to what it can use (????) or is there a way to allocate more.  As my project is growing, the problem is becoming more and more frequent.

Anyone else suffering from this ?? Any ideas on how to resolve ??